# How to get the total count in an year

Tags: java

Get Counts for every Year

This is what I have tried

```
public static void main(String args[])
{       
    List<Map<String,Integer>> list_map = new ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>();

    Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    map1.put("Year",2018);
    map1.put("Month",1);
    map1.put("Cost",100);

    list_map.add(map1);

    Map<String,Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    map2.put("Year",2018);
    map2.put("Month",2);
    map2.put("Cost",200);

    list_map.add(map2);

    Map<String,Integer> map3 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    map3.put("Year",2018);
    map3.put("Month",3);
    map3.put("Cost",300);

    list_map.add(map3);

    Map<String,Integer> map4 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    map4.put("Year",2017);
    map4.put("Month",1);
    map4.put("Cost",400);

    list_map.add(map4);

    Map<String,Integer> map5 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    map5.put("Year",2017);
    map5.put("Month",2);
    map5.put("Cost",500);

    list_map.add(map5);

    Map<String,Integer> map6 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    map6.put("Year",2017);
    map6.put("Month",3);
    map6.put("Cost",300);

    list_map.add(map6);


    Iterator<Map<String,Integer>> iterator = list_map.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {           
         Map<String,Integer> year = iterator.next();

         Set<Entry<String,Integer>> entrySet = year.entrySet();

         for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : entrySet) 
            {                
                System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +" " + "\tValue : " + entry.getValue());
            }   
         System.out.println();       
    }
```

output

```
Key : Month     Value : 1
Key : Year  Value : 2018
Key : Cost  Value : 100

Key : Month     Value : 2
Key : Year  Value : 2018
Key : Cost  Value : 200

Key : Month     Value : 3
Key : Year  Value : 2018
Key : Cost  Value : 300

Key : Month     Value : 1
Key : Year  Value : 2017
Key : Cost  Value : 400

Key : Month     Value : 2
Key : Year  Value : 2017
Key : Cost  Value : 500

Key : Month     Value : 3
Key : Year  Value : 2017
Key : Cost  Value : 300
```

Expected Output

```
Year    Count
2018     600
2017     1200
```

Comment: i guess you would need to apply if conditions?

Comment: Did you try using streams with `groupingBy` year and summing the entries for the same year?

Comment: No, I need to create one more list to get the expected output

Comment: Yes , I need to go with if statement, but how to do it

Comment: @Anonymous Is there a specific reason you're using a `Map` rather than a dedicated class for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Andronicus answer will be great. And Ali Azim too, but my variant more small.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> yearCounts = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<String, Integer> year : list_map) {

    if (yearCounts.containsKey(year.get("Year"))) {
        Integer count = yearCounts.get(year.get("Year"));
        yearCounts.put(year.get("Year"), year.get("Cost") + count);
    } else {
        yearCounts.put(year.get("Year"), year.get("Cost"));
    }
}

System.out.println("Year\tCount");

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> yearCount : yearCounts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(yearCount.getKey() + "\t" + yearCount.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent case for using streams.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> yearStats = listMap.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.get("Year"), Collectors.summingInt(t -> t.get("Cost"))));
```

**Explanation:**

With the `stream` method, a stream operation is initialized in order to walk over the elements of the stream. In this case, each element is a `Map`. Then we use a collector which groups by the value of the `Year` key of the map, so it will give us results for each year. The second argument to the `Collector.groupingBy` method allows us to pass in another `Collector`. We pass in a `summingInt` collector, which collects elements from a stream adding all elements.

---

By the way, is there a reason you're using a `Map` rather than a specific class?

```
class A {
    int year;
    int month;
    int cost;
}
```